# Create quaternion from euler in arduino

Tags: arduino, ros-kinetic, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

How to create a quaternion from Euler angles in arduino?

In python it is possible to use this function:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
import tf
.
.
.
odom_orientation = Quaternion()
odom_orientation = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0.0, 0.0, th)
```

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337231/create-quaternion-from-euler-in-arduino/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
since you just want yaw and not pitch and roll, you can use the following:

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);
```

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2019-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-11-09**:
Add the following includes:

```
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
```

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-11-09**:
More generally: http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a66cb77b973c0db55c3ab8bbee4ac781b